# How to customise terminal to condense my the path to show just the current folder?

Tags: settings, pantheon-terminal

It gets pretty long when I'm deep in my folder structure and it sometimes covers the line in the terminal.

Secondly how to show git branch if the folder is git initiated?

Thirdly, how to funk up a few things to make it look cool?

How to set in terminal shortcut to open a new tab in the current terminal on pressing Ctrl + N?

Comment: You should ask separate questions because there are 2 or 4 separate questions and threads here. As for your last question look at http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/open-a-new-tab-in-terminal-instead-of-a-new-window

Comment: Thank you. I thought it might serve as a good document for all those who want to tweak their Pantheon terminal, hence all in one question.

Comment: Actually for tweaking path you can look at any bash/sh resources at other stack overflow sites (I would suggest that you start at unix&linux) I don't think there is much pantheon terminal specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first three questions is [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline).
I personally also used [fish](http://fishshell.com/), which is cool if you don't care for compatibility. If you do, the answer is zsh and particularly [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your bash prompt by editing the `PS1` and `PS2` environment variables. [Digital Ocean's Bash Prompt tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-bash-prompt-on-a-linux-vps) explains how this works. You could also use a tool like [EZPrompt](http://ezprompt.net/) to generate the variable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link:
[Prompt branches and tab completion](https://www.learnenough.com/git-tutorial#sec-prompt_branches_and_tab_completion)

This will show just the current folder and if inside a git repository it will show the current branch as well.